# What is the meaning of the type of reference

Tags: java, dynamic, reference, reference-type, dynamic-binding

```
class Parent {
    int m;
}

class child extends Parent {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Parent x = new Child(); 
    }
}
```

What is the meaning when we say `x is of type Parent`? Why do we make use of 
such referencing while we can use `Child x = new Child()`?

Comment: Downvoted for lack of prior research.

Answer (score 0):

A `List<Shape>` can contain rectangles, circles, if those are subtypes of `Shape`.
That's an example for why it's good.

Comment: Read about [polymorphism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html) for more examples.

Comment: I can use a list to add stuff. What can I then do if I have a Parent type reference? I can not add anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

Java resolve the class of an object dynamically. It means that the actual type of an object is resolved over the indicated type.

So, in your example, if `Child` contains an overloaded method from `Parent`, this method will be called first before the one inheritted from `Parent`.